Why datetime writen into json field has invalid value?
In laravel 10 app  I need to write into json field info on logged user with time of logging
I do it with code :
\Log::info(varDump($timezone, ' -1 $timezone::'));
\Log::info(varDump(Carbon::now($timezone), ' -1 BEFORE EXIT Carbon::now($timezone)::'));
return KeyData::create([
    'key' => $key,
    'data' => [["user_id" => $loggedUserId, "online_from" => Carbon::now($timezone), 'temp_field' => 'temp_value']],
    'expired_at' => Carbon::now($timezone)->addSeconds($cachingTimeInSeconds)
]);

Checking logging output I see valid timezone and time in date field with timezone.
-1 $timezone:: : Europe/Kiev
[2024-05-23 10:03:10] local.INFO:  (Object of Carbon\Carbon) : -1 BEFORE EXIT Carbon::now($timezone):: : Array
(
    [ * endOfTime] =>
    [ * startOfTime] =>
    [ * constructedObjectId] => 000000000000055b0000000000000000
    [ * localMonthsOverflow] =>
    [ * localYearsOverflow] =>
    [ * localStrictModeEnabled] =>
    [ * localHumanDiffOptions] =>
    [ * localToStringFormat] =>
    [ * localSerializer] =>
    [ * localMacros] =>
    [ * localGenericMacros] =>
    [ * localFormatFunction] =>
    [ * localTranslator] =>
    [ * dumpProperties] => Array
        (
            [0] => date
            [1] => timezone_type
            [2] => timezone
        )

    [ * dumpLocale] =>
    [ * dumpDateProperties] =>
    [date] => 2024-05-23 10:03:10.253696
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Kiev
)

But checking data I see that value in "online_from" is invalid :

Table is created with migration :
    Schema::create('key_data', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('key', 255);
        $table->json('data')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('expired_at');
        $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();

        $table->index(['key', 'expired_at'], 'key_data_key_expired_at_index');
    });

Checking collation I see :
CREATE TABLE `key_data` (
`id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`data` json DEFAULT NULL,
`expired_at` datetime NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `key_data_key_expired_at_index` (`key`,`expired_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

What is wrong and how that can be fixed ?

Make sure the DateTime is in the correct format (e.g. ISO 8601) before inserting it in the JSON. I think you're seeing different results because your logger may convert the DateTime into a more legible format.
$now = Carbon::now($timezone)->toIso8601String();
$expiry = Carbon::now($timezone)->addSeconds($cachingTimeInSeconds)->toIso8601String();

return KeyData::create([
    'key' => $key,
    'data' => [["user_id" => $loggedUserId, "online_from" => $now, 'temp_field' => 'temp_value']],
    'expired_at' => $expiry
]);


Yes, I applied method ->toIso8601String() to value assigned in json only and it works. Is it some featurew of json field?

I my model I defined :    protected $casts = [ 'data' => 'array', 'created_at' => 'datetime', 'expired_at' => 'datetime' ];  Can it be related ?

As I mentioned in my answer - your logger probably converts the datetime object into the Iso8601 format automatically. JSON is just raw data. So if you want your JSON to contain your DateTime in Iso8601 format, you have to insert the Iso8601 representation of your DateTime object, not the DateTime object itself.
